# How and when iOS kills an app which is in background for long time?

Tags: ios, iphone, application-lifecycle

I want to know what happens when the app comes to foreground after being in background for long time? How basically iOS works to free up memory and how it kills the app.

Answer (score 1):

Check [The App Life Cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html) document. `Execution States for Apps` in particular.